# How to compute values in lightning-datatable when cell change

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

I am attempting to perform calculations when there is a change in a cell. Specifically, if the values of either Q1__c or Q2__c change, then I want to compute the value of First_Half_Amount__c (i.e., First_Half_Amount__c = Q1__c + Q2__c). However, the calculation is only triggered when both values change.

Eg. if i change only Q1__c value its not changing the First_Half_Amount__c
[image]

if i change both value then its calculating and updating the First_Half_Amount__c cell.

if i change both its calucalting properly and updating the First_Half_Amount__c
[image]

```
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.getCases';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Category_T__c';
import TYPE_DFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Sub_Category_T__c';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';



 import {createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const columns = [

    {
        label: 'Spend Category', fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Spend Sub Category', fieldName: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistDColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListDOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },

    { label: 'Line Item Description', fieldName: 'Line_Item_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Calculation Description', fieldName: 'Calculation_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'NGO and ILP Discussion', fieldName: 'NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q1', fieldName: 'Q1__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q2', fieldName: 'Q2__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q3', fieldName: 'Q3__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q4', fieldName: 'Q4__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'First Half Actuals', fieldName: 'First_Half_Actuals__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Second Half Actuals', fieldName: 'Second_Half_Actuals__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'First Half Budget', fieldName: 'First_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: false },
    { label: 'Second Half Budget', fieldName: 'Second_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: false },
    { label: 'Total Annual Budget', fieldName: 'Total_Annual_Budget__c', type: 'currency', editable: false },
    { label: 'Total Annual Actuals', fieldName: 'Total_Annual_Actuals__c', type: 'currency', editable: false },
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        fixedWidth: 34,
        typeAttributes:
        {
            iconName: 'utility:delete',
            name: 'delete',
            iconClass: 'slds-icon-text-error'
        }
    },
    
]

export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    showSpinner = false;
     data = [];
     accountData;
     draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
     pickListOptions;
     pickListDOptions;
    @track totalAnnualActualsSum=0;
    @track totalAnnualBudgetsSum=0;
    @api recordId;
    @track records;

    error;
    @api selectedRows;
    @track tableErrors = { rows: {}, table: {} };



    @api constant = {
        ERROR_TITLE : 'Error Found',
        ROWACTION_DELETE : 'delete',
        VAR_SUCCESS : 'Success',
        VAR_ERROR : 'error',
        MSG_DELETE : 'Record Deleted',
        MSG_ERR_DEL : 'Error deleting record',
        MSG_ERR_UPD_RELOAD : 'Error updating or reloading record',
        MSG_UPD : 'Contact Updated',
        DEL_CONFIRM : 'Want to delete?',
        MODE_BATCH : 'batch',
        MODE_SINGLE : 'single'
    }




    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
    })

    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('Picklist'+data)
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_DFIELD
    })

    wireDPickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('DPicklist',data.values);
            this.pickListDOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListDOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    //here I pass picklist option so that this wire method call after above method
    @wire(fetchAccounts, { pickList: '$pickListOptions',pickDList:'$pickListDOptions' })
    accountData(result) {
        this.accountData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));

            this.data.forEach(ele => {
                ele.pickListOptions = this.pickListOptions;
                ele.pickListDOptions=this.pickListDOptions;
                this.totalAnnualBudgetsSum+=Number(ele.Total_Annual_Budget__c);
                this.totalAnnualActualsSum+=Number(ele.Total_Annual_Actuals__c);
            })

            this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        } else if (result.error) {
            console.log('error',result.error)
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    };


/**
   *
   * @param {object} event
   * @returns
   */

handleRowAction(event) {
    try {
        const action = event.detail.action.name;

        switch (action) {
            case this.constant.ROWACTION_DELETE:
                this.rowactionDelete(event);
                break;
            }
    } catch (errorMsg) {
        console.log('Error occurred inside handleRowAction() method', errorMsg);
    }
}


         /**
   * case (d.2): DELETE records (ONLY single row)
   *        (a) single record can be deleted
   * called from JS - handleRowAction()
   * @param {object} event
   * @returns
   */

    rowactionDelete(event) {

        //confirm to delete & invoke deleteRecord()

         if (window.confirm(this.constant.DEL_CONFIRM)) {

             deleteRecord(event.detail.row.Id)
             .then(() => {
                 this.dispatchEvent(
                     new ShowToastEvent({
                         title: this.constant.VAR_SUCCESS,
                         message: this.constant.MSG_DELETE,
                         variant: this.constant.VAR_SUCCESS
                     })
                 );

             //refresh data in the datatable
             return refreshApex(this.accountData);
             })

             //display error message in case of errors
             .catch(error => {
                 this.dispatchEvent(
                     new ShowToastEvent({
                         title: this.constant.MSG_ERR_DEL,
                         message: error.body.message,
                         variant: this.constant.VAR_ERROR
                     })
                 );
             });
         }
     }


    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });

        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty('Q1__c') || item.hasOwnProperty('Q2__c')) {
                    item.First_Half_Amount__c = parseFloat(item.Q1__c) + parseFloat(item.Q1__c);
                    console.log('item.First_Half_Amount__c',item.First_Half_Amount__c)
                }
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }


handleCellChange(event) {
    let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    draftValues.forEach((ele) => {
        this.updateDraftValues(ele);
        const updatedRow = this.data.find((row) => row.Id === ele.Id);
        if (ele.hasOwnProperty('Spend_Category_T__c')) {
            const selectedCategory = ele.Spend_Category_T__c;

            // Filter dependent picklist options based on the selected category
            const filteredDOptions = this.pickListDOptions.filter((option) => {
                // Implement your logic here to filter based on the category
                return option.validFor.includes(this.pickListOptions.findIndex((item) => item.value === selectedCategory));
            });

            // Update only the specific row's dependent picklist options
            updatedRow.pickListDOptions = filteredDOptions;
        }
    });

    // Update only the specific rows that have been modified
    this.data = [...this.data];
}


       handleSave(event) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.saveDraftValues = this.draftValues;

        const recordInputs = [];
        const newrecordInputs = [];


        this.saveDraftValues.forEach(draft => {
            if (draft.Id.startsWith("a07")) {
                recordInputs.push({
                    fields: Object.assign({}, draft)
                });
            } else {
                draft.Id = '';
                draft.First_Half_Amount__c = 50;
                draft.Project_Yearly_Plan__c = this.recordId;
                const { Id, ...fields } = draft;
                newrecordInputs.push({
                    apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName,
                    fields
                });
            }
        });


        if (recordInputs.length > 0) {
            const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
            Promise.all(promises)
                .then(res => {
                    this.showToast('Success', 'Records Updated Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
                    this.draftValues = [];
                    return this.refresh();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occurred while updating records!', 'error', 'dismissable');
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.draftValues = [];
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                });
        }


        if (newrecordInputs.length > 0) {
            const promises = newrecordInputs.map(recordInput => createRecord(recordInput));
            Promise.all(promises)
                .then(res => {
                    this.showToast('Success', 'Records Created Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
                    this.draftValues = [];
                    return this.refresh();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occurred while creating records!', 'error', 'dismissable');
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.draftValues = [];
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                });
        }
    }





    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    // This function is used to refresh the table once data updated
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.accountData);
    }

    handleAddRow() {
        // Create a new blank row with default values
        const newRow = {
            Id: Math.random().toString(), // Generate a unique identifier if needed
            Name: '',
            Spend_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Spend_Sub_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Line_Item_Description__c: '',
            Calculation_Description__c: '',
            NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c: '',
            Q1__c: '',
            Q2__c: '',
            Q3__c: '',
            Q4__c: '',
            First_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Second_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Total_Annual_Budget__c: '',
            pickListOptions:this.pickListOptions || [],
            pickListDOptions:this.pickListDOptions || [],
        };

        this.data = [newRow, ...this.data ];
   // this.draftValues = [...this.draftValues, newRow];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the main value if there's no draft value. That approximately looks like:

```
updateDraftValues(draftValue) {
  const row = this.data.find(item => draftValue.Id === item.Id);
  // Best practice to always use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
  // See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-prototype-builtins
  const own = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
  const hasQ1 = own.call(draftValue,'Q1__c');
  const hasQ2 = own.call(draftValue,'Q2__c');
  if(hasQ1 || hasQ2) {
    draftValue.First_Half_Amount__c = 
      parseFloat((hasQ1?draftValue:row).Q1__c || 0) + 
      parseFloat((hasQ2?draftValue:row).Q2__c || 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, 

thanks for your response
I have updated code as per your suggestion. Instead checking draftvalues i have updating main values. but im getting an error

Comment: handleCellChange(event) {
  let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
   draftValues.forEach((ele) => {
      this.updateDraftValues(ele);
      const updatedRow = this.data.find((row) => row.Id === ele.Id);
      const own = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
      const hasQ1 = own.call(ele,'Q1__c');
      const hasQ2 = own.call(ele,'Q2__c');
     if(hasQ1 || hasQ2) {
             ele.First_Half_Amount__c = parseFloat((hasQ1?ele:row).Q1__c || 0) + 
              parseFloat((hasQ2?ele:row).Q2__c || 0);
  }
       updatedRow.pickListDOptions = filteredDOptions;
        } 
    });

Comment: @Afroseahamed What is the error?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox

Man. You are great! Thank you so much its working as expected.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,
One more question i need to validate q1 and q2 value greater than zero. if enter less than zero its throwing an error. if i change another row its throwin an error but previous q1 row error not showing

Comment: @Afroseahamed that's probably better as a separate question so I can visualize it, but I would say that it's probably because the table is rendering again. You can use the `errors` property to show all the appropriate errors. See the documentation for more details.